# Internal Error in OpenSUSE Upgrader

Tags: grub, opensuse, bios

I'm trying to upgrade a very old, 32-bit OpenSUSE 13.2 to 64-bit Leap 15.1 by booting from the Leap DVD. The "Analyzing" phase runs into an internal error:

```
Internal error. Please report a bug with logs. Run save_y2logs to get complete logs.

Caller: /mounts/mp_0001/usr/share/YaST2/lib/bootloader/udev_mapping.rb:82: in `udev_to_kernel`

Details: Error reading the bootloader configuration files. Please use the YaST2 bootloader to fix it. 

Details: Unknown udev device '(hd0,2)'
```

(I've been using Grub on legacy BIOS to boot. (hd0,2) was always simply the standard way of referring to partition 2 on the first hard drive.)

Is this just an unimportant failure on the part of the OpenSUSE engineers to anticipate a very old previous boot setup, or will it cause the upgrade to fail? Obviously I don't want to end up in a state where I can boot neither the original nor the old system.